# Angular app downloading bundled JS twice, is this a mistake?

Tags: angular

I have an Angular 7 app. I'm working on the performance.
I have noticed that the apps JS bundle seems to be downloading twice on start up.

Why might the app be doing this? How would I find where this is happening?

The site is currently at [www.tilecase.com](https://www.tilecase.com)

[image: JS downloading twice]

Comment: Ben I would say this is a mistake. I noticed that on the site both of those bundles are being downloaded from different source locations.  Is that intentional? My guess is this would have to be configured in the angular.json file.

Comment: Thanks for the help. So do I want the preload link as well as the other link? Should there only be one?

Comment: If you have two it will load two.  I just can't think of a reason off the top of my head that you would need it loaded twice.  I would think one overwrites the other